# Rating system : How to select the next item for which the user didn't vote yet

Tags: mysql, sql, rating, vote

I have 3 tables with the following columns :

```
* users : user_id
* votes : user_id, creation_id
* creations : creation_id, creation_points
```

Each `user` can vote one time for each `creation`. When a user vote, this happens :

- Table `votes` : Insert a new line with `user_id` and `creation_id` (so we can check if the user has already voted for this creation)
- Table `creations` : Add +1 to row `creation_points` for the concerned creation

But now, I want that when the user has successfully voted for a creation, it displays him the **next** creation for which he didn't vote yet. How can I achieve that ?

I tried this way :

1. Select the next `creation_id` from `creations` table (where `creation_id` is bigger than the current `creation_id`)
2. Check if the couple `creation_id` & `user_id` already exists in the `votes` table. If it exists, retry from 1).

The problem with this method is that it needs a lot of queries if the user has already voted for the next creation. It also create an infinite loop if he has already voted for all the creations. Is there others alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand how you are handling it, you seem to be on the right track by storing `votes` as a `user_id` and `creation_id`.  To get the next available creation, use a `LIMIT 1` query that excludes the already voted-for creations:

This method uses a `NOT IN()` subquery:

```
SELECT 
 creations.*
FROM creations 
WHERE creation_id NOT IN (
  SELECT creation_id FROM votes WHERE user_id = <the user_id>
)
ORDER BY creation_id ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Similar thing using `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT 
 creations.*
FROM creations 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT creation_id 
  FROM votes 
  WHERE 
   user_id = <the user_id>
   AND creations.creation_id = votes.creation_id
)
ORDER BY creation_id ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a join on votes table

if your current creation_id = 123456

your user id = 789

```
SELECT c.creation_id 
FROM creations AS c 
INNER JOIN votes AS v ON v.creation_id = c.creations_id 
WHERE c.creation_id > 123456 AND v.user_id != 789 
ORDER BY c.creation_id ASC 
LIMIT 0,1
```